# Change pandas dataframe format from wide to long similar to pd.melt

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
| id1 | id2 | source_id1 | source2_id2 | panel_id1 | panel_id2 |
| --- | --- | ---------- | ----------- | --------- | --------- |
| 123 | qwe | de         | MET         | nq        | TIM       |
| 145 |     | de         |             | nq        |           |
|     | qaz |            | MET         |           | TIM       |
```

And I want to turn it into:

```
| id  | source | panel |
| --- | ------ | ----- |
| 123 | de     | nq    |
| qwe | MET    | TIM   |
| 145 | de     | nq    |
| qaz | MET    | TIM   |
```

I've tried to do it with `pd.melt`, but since I don't have 2 `id_vars` it's not working how I want. Anyone know how I can turn the first df into long structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be easier to seperate the data and stick them back together like this:

```
cols1 = ['id1', 'source_id1', 'panel_id1']
cols2 = ['id2', 'source2_id2', 'panel_id2']

df1 = df[cols1].copy().dropna()
df2 = df[cols2].copy().dropna()

df1.columns = ['id', 'source_id', 'panel_id']
df2.columns = ['id', 'source_id', 'panel_id']

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: This seems to be the simplest way of doing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use  [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html) to abstract the process. Your  columns have a pattern (some start with `id`, some with `source`, some with `panel`). Let's pass a list of regular expressions that capture this pattern:

```
( df.pivot_longer(index=None, 
                  names_to=("id", "source", "panel"), 
                  names_pattern=[r"^id", r"^source", r"^panel"])
   .query("id != ''")
 )

    id source panel
0  123     de    nq
1  145     de    nq
3  qwe    MET   TIM
5  qaz    MET   TIM
```

In the code above, we pass the new column names to `names_to`, and the list of regular expressions to `names_pattern`.

Comment: Thanks, this solution look neat, but I will accept @Andreas answer, because with my current set up it will be harder to use another external library.